# <button type="submit"> apex equivalent

Tags: apex, html, button

I would like to know I would be able to convert the following codes into apex equivalent.

```
<button type="submit">
    <span></span>
</button>
```

I can't use `<apex:commandButton>`, as it is being rendered as `<input>` which is a single tag. I need to add an icon into the button that's why I have a `<span>` inside the button tag as I am using bootstrap.

Comment: You can use that code directly without modification, you can call an apex:action function on click if you need to do so

Answer (score 4):

To further illustrate Eric's comment, You would implement his suggestion like so:

Define your button (the button calls the javascript function `doSomething`) that is defined by the `actionFunction`:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="doSomething()">
    <span></span>
</button>
```

Define your controller action:

```
public PageReference doSomething(){
    //do something
    return null;
}
```

Define your `actionFunction` (this calls the controller action):

```
<apex:actionFunction name="doSomething" action="{!doSomething}"
    rerender="someApexObjectOnThePageEgAPanel" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a follow up question, the original element that calls the action is <apex:commandButton  action="{!search}">. Should i put the action in the button tag as onclick="{!search}" or onclick="search()"?

Comment: if your action is "{!search}" then you should have the `actionFunction` call the "search" method on the controller. Your `onclick` event calls the NAME of the `actionFunction` - if you call it "search" then your onclick would be onclick="search()" if you call it "searchAction" then your onclick would be onclick="searchAction()"

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!actionMethod}"  styleclass="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse">
   <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--large" aria-hidden="true">
    <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close')}"></use>
   </svg>
</apex:commandLink>
```

where i'm displaying the close icon and on clicking it I need to call "actionMethod" of controller.